# Frequency Domain Filtering opencv c++?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing

Actually I want to apply notch filter to remove specific pattern in image just like (line ,circle ,etc..) . I want to remove some specific frequency of line or circle using notch filter or any other way of removing.  Can some one guide me how can I remove specific repetitive  pattern from image just like circle or line. if you give some example code it help me a lot. because currently I can not understand how I apply filter or notch to remove certain repetitive pattern form Image. Waiting to hear from you soon.[image]

Comment: Does my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235421/find-proper-notch-filter-to-remove-pattern-from-image) question help? It's a matlab related question but the explanation should stand on its own.

Comment: Posting an image might help.

Comment: @MarkSetchell please see the image and guide me how can I remove the repetitive Line structure from image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spectral Analysis is not *"my thing"*, but the steps are as follows.

Take your original image and perform FFT to generate:

- phase image
- magnitude image
- spectrum (on a log scale)

You seem to have that already. Now take the spectrum image:

[image]

and mask out all the off-centre highlights with a different colour, like this:

[image]

and difference that with the original spectrum so you get a mask of your edits like this:

[image]

Multiply that newest mask with the original magnitude, combine with the original phase and do the inverse FFT. I got this as a result of my sloppy editing and abilities!

[image]

Comment: Please Can you share the code it give me more help to play with. Thanks

Comment: I didn’t use **OpenCV** as I was just showing the technique and I didn’t want to write, compile and test code. I just used **ImageMagick** at the commandline to do the FFT, difference, multiply and Inverse FFT.